# CSS scale and square center crop image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

So I have a collection of thumbnails in my app, which is the size of *200x200*. Sometimes the original image doesn't have this ratio so I am planning to crop this image to a square.

Currently it just streches the image to fit into the thumbnail, so say my original image size is *400x800*, then the image looks very squished. I wanted to crop this image so it looks at the shortest width/height and then crop it to a square, so in my example above it will be cropped to a *400x400*.

Is there a way to easily do this via CSS or do I have to use some sort of JS to do this?

Comment: Although you did describe your problem, it is greatly appreciated to be able to see some code. Consider adding some code so that your question will have a much higher value

Comment: @CodyGuldner, I think the point here is that his he doesn't know what code to use.  His question seems fine to me.

Comment: @CodyGuldner if I had some code then I would really show it out here.. but I don't have any as of this point

Comment: This is easily done if you can make the image be a background image of a div. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UXgVF/1/) showing how.    If you need to use the `img` tag, then my css-fu is not good enough to help you, but I'll bet it's possible.

Comment: So if I understand your question correctly, you want to keep the aspect ratio of an image, but you want to turn it into a square by cropping it?

Comment: @Cody - if you crop an image, it wouldn't be the same aspect ratio.

Comment: @CodyGuldner I don't want to keep the aspect ratio, I just wanted to crop it as a square if the image is not already a square, that's all.

Comment: I found [this](http://cssglobe.com/3-easy-and-fast-css-techniques-for-faux-image/) article by doing a simple google search

Comment: @CodyGuldner so I'd have some cases and have to use some if statements to determine the cropping, so I assume a js?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can do this easily in CSS if you use background-image.

```
.thumb {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 3px solid #c99;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

In this fiddle, first image is 400x800, second image is 800x400:

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/tx7sf

Comment: Careful this wont work in all browser versions, this is CSS3 markup so unless you are marketing to a particular browser you should consider an alternative approach.

Answer (score 10):

**Updated** to handle cases where image width is greater than height.

You can do this with pure CSS. Set the container element of each image to have fixed height and width and `overflow: hidden`. Then set the image within to have `min-width: 100%`, `min-height: 100%`. Any extra height or width will overflow the container and be hidden.

*HTML*

```
<div class="thumb">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/800" alt="" />
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
.thumb {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

.thumb img {
    display: block; /* Otherwise it keeps some space around baseline */
    min-width: 100%;    /* Scale up to fill container width */
    min-height: 100%;   /* Scale up to fill container height */
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; /* Scaled images look a bit better in IE now */
}
```

Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/thefrontender/XZP9U/5/

Comment: What about an image which is wider than it is tall?

Comment: @Mathletics then we just update the CSS to set both min-width and min-height to 100% as per this updated Fiddle: jsfiddle.net/thefrontender/XZP9U/5 I've also updated the answer. We lose the ability to scale an image down, but it's still a valid pure CSS solution that fills the square space without distorting the original image

Comment: is it possible to have centered images ? usually top-left corner doesn't say much...

Answer (score 1):

I came up with my own solution and thought I would share it here in case anyone else found this thread. The background-size: cover solution is the easiest, but I needed something that would work in IE7 as well. Here's what I came up with using jQuery and CSS.

Note: My images were "profile" images and needed to be cropped to squares. Hence some of the function names.

**jQuery:**

```
cropProfileImage = function(pic){
    var h = $(pic).height(),
        w = $(pic).width();

    if($(pic).parent('.profile-image-wrap').length === 0){
                     // wrap the image in a "cropping" div
         $(pic).wrap('<div class="profile-image-wrap"></div>');
    }

      if(h > w ){
          // pic is portrait
          $(pic).addClass('portrait');
          var m = -(((h/w) * 100)-100)/2; //math the negative margin
          $(pic).css('margin-top', m + '%');    
      }else if(w > h){ 
          // pic is landscape
          $(pic).addClass('landscape'); 
          var m = -(((w/h) * 100)-100)/2;  //math the negative margin
          $(pic).css('margin-left', m + '%');
      }else {
        // pic is square
        $(pic).addClass('square');
      }
 }

// Call the function for the images you want to crop
cropProfileImage('img.profile-image');
```

**CSS**

```
.profile-image { visibility: hidden; } /* prevent a flash of giant image before the image is wrapped by jQuery */

.profile-image-wrap { 
      /* whatever the dimensions you want the "cropped" image to be */
      height: 8em;
      width: 8em;
      overflow: hidden; 
 }

.profile-image-wrap img.square {
      visibility: visible;
      width: 100%;  
 }

 .profile-image-wrap img.portrait {
      visibility: visible;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
 }

 .profile-image-wrap img.landscape {
      visibility: visible;
      height: 100%;
      width: auto;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### 2023 answer

```css
img {
    width: 400px; /* Determines size of square */
    aspect-ratio: 1/1; /* width height proportion */
    object-fit: cover; /* No distortion */
}
```

```html
<img src="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/421/900/500.jpg?hmac=8qd7cfSLwCup5MJhUfNHXpv3YV5SBP5w4rqxalOOObc" />
```