# Background image spinner when not loaded

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, image, angularjs-directive

Using a `div` with

```
<div ng-style="{'background-image':'url('+image+')'}"></div>
```

I would like to show a spinner in the `div` while the background image has not yet been fully loaded. How is that possible? I want to use the `background-image` for displaying the image (and not the `src`) since I want to [crop and center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310918/css-scale-and-square-center-crop-image) my images.

Comment: Did you find any way to add spinner to this ?

Answer (score 0):

Set a 'loading'  variable on your scope to true when loading and then false when loaded.

Use ng-class in the template to set the class with the background image when 'loading' e.g. ng-class="{'loading-class': loading} "

Use onloadeddata event [Angular on video load event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28016476/1401202)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you please add to your answer how I would detect if the background images are loading?

Comment: There is no load event for background images ?

Comment: How about adding the image to $templateCache?